# Integration involving irrational exponent

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**Question:**

> If: $$I = \int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^{\pi/2}}$$ then:
>
> a) $\ln2 < I < \frac{\pi}{4}$
>
> b) $I < \ln2$
>
> c) $I > \frac{\pi}{4}$
>
> d) None of these

I have no idea how to approach this question. How am I supposed to integrate with the irrational exponent of $x$?

Comment: Fortunately, you don't need to know the exact value.   A sufficiently good numerical approximation will do.

Comment: Inspired from asymptotics: if you use $1/(1+x)=1-x+x^2-\cdots$ to expand your integrand, you can obtain the result as a power series in $1/(\pi/2)$. Combining consecutive plus and minus terms in pairs, you may find something useful.

Comment: @Chip Not sure I understand... Mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: Not sure is worth to be answer...You can write ($a=\pi/2$): $1/(1+x^a) = 1 - x^a + x^{2a}-\cdots$ and you integrate that term by term. You get a series in $1/a$. You can further add the second and third term, the fourth and the fifth, etc to get a cleaner expression. Then, you look what you get when you replace $a=\pi/2$?

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I guess I lied, sorry!

Comment: Wolfram gives a closed form for the indefinite integral of $1/(1+x^{11/7})$ :)  http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=1%2F%281%2Bx%5E%2811%2F7%29%29&random=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $3 < \pi < 4$ so that $1.5 < \pi/2 < 2$.

(Or directly recall that $\pi/2 = 1.57\ldots$ if this is at your fingertips!)

Well, one technique now is to round down to the integer below, and round up to the integer above.

That is, consider your definite integral where $\pi/2$ is replaced with $1$ and then with $2$.

In each case, compute the result exactly.

How do these results compare to -- i.e., bound! -- the initial integral?

Comment: Aha.... May I know where this technique came from?

Comment: There is the general concept of, if I don't know *exactly* what something is, then I may *estimate* it by finding something definitely smaller than it *and* something definitely larger than it. In the particular context given, I learned this when I took a course on Calculus! Incidentally, the professor with whom I took this class (Norton Starr) wrote a nice paper in the MAA's *College Mathematics Journal* entitled: [**Estimating Definite Integrals**](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/starr01200504131.pdf). Give it a look!

Comment: I see... This will be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, can this be considered an application of the sandwich theorem for integration?

Comment: @Gummybears I usually think of the *sandwich* (or *squeeze*) *theorem* as a situation in which you give an object a lower bound and an upper bound, and then, by showing that the two bounds are equal, conclude that your object is the same, as well. In practice, this often happens when you are in a situation related to taking limits ([**wiki**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Following the @Chip hint, we can perform the integration in terms of the digamma function $\Psi$ as follows:

\begin{align}
I & \equiv \int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over 1 + x^{\pi/2}} =
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}x^{n\pi/2}\,\dd x =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n\pi/2 + 1} =
{2 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n + 2/\pi}
\\[3mm] &=
{2 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\pars{{1 \over 2n + 2/\pi} - {1 \over 2n + 1 + 2/\pi}} =
{2 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{2n + 2/\pi}\pars{2n + 1 + 2/\pi}}
\\[3mm] & =
{1 \over 2\pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{n + 1/2 + 1/\pi}\pars{n + 1/\pi}} =
{1 \over 2\pi}\,{\Psi\pars{1/2 + 1/\pi} - \Psi\pars{1/\pi} \over \pars{1/2 + 1/\pi} - 1/\pi}
\\[3mm] & =
\color{#f00}{{1 \over \pi}\,
\bracks{\Psi\pars{\half + {1 \over \pi}} - \Psi\pars{1 \over \pi}}} \approx
0.7533\quad\imp\quad0.6931 = \ln\pars{2} < I < {\pi \over 4} \approx 0.7854
\end{align}

We were not able to get the result by direct manipulation of the digamma involved final result.

Answer (score 0):

For $0 < x < 1$, we have $x^2 < x^{\pi/2} <x$. Use these two bound and you can integrate exactly.